# Phaser GameObjectFactory function is undefined

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am using `GameObjectFactory` to register `myPlayer`

```
import Phaser from 'phaser'
import Player from './Player'
import { Direction } from '@/types/phaser';

export default class MyPlayer extends Player {
  constructor(
    scene: Phaser.Scene,
    x: number,
    y: number,
    defaultDirection: Direction
  ) {
    super(scene, x, y, defaultDirection)
    scene.add.existing(this)
  }
}

declare global {
  namespace Phaser.GameObjects {
    interface GameObjectFactory {
      myPlayer(x: number, y: number, defaultDirection: Direction): MyPlayer
    }
  }
}

Phaser.GameObjects.GameObjectFactory.register(
  'myPlayer',
  function (
    this: Phaser.GameObjects.GameObjectFactory,
    x: number,
    y: number,
    defaultDirection: Direction
  ) {
    const sprite = new MyPlayer(this.scene, x, y, defaultDirection)

    this.displayList.add(sprite)
    this.updateList.add(sprite)

    return sprite
  }
)
```

I try to use `this.add.myPlayer` in my scene

```
import Phaser from 'phaser'
import MyPlayer from '@/players/MyPlayer'
import { CustomCursorKeys } from '@/types/phaser'
import { Direction } from '@/types/phaser'

export default class BaseScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  public cursors: CustomCursorKeys | null = null
  public myPlayer: MyPlayer | null = null

  constructor(key: string) {
    super(key)
  }

  create(param: { 
    map: Phaser.Tilemaps.Tilemap, 
    x: number, 
    y: number, 
    direction: Direction 
  }) {
    console.log('this.add.myPlayer', this.add.myPlayer)
    this.myPlayer = this.add.myPlayer(705, 500, 'up')
  }
}
```

But `this.add.myPlayer` console logs as `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the best would be if you try to keep your code as close to [this offical example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/plugins/custom-game-object).

You would have to create your own *custom Object/Sprite*, create a *custom Plugin* and *register* the plugin in the *game-config*.

**Here is a possible example, how this could look like:**

***Player File:***
*(add a Plugin for registering a plugin)*

```js
import Phaser from 'phaser'
import Player from './Player'
import { Direction } from '@/types/phaser';

export default class MyPlayer extends Player {
    ...
}

export class MPlayerPlugin extends Phaser.Plugins.BasePlugin {
    constructor (pluginManager) {
        super(pluginManager);
        pluginManager.registerGameObject('mPlayer', this.createMPlayer);
    }

    createMPlayer ( x: number, y: number, defaultDirection: Direction) {
        return this.displayList.add(new MyPlayer(this.scene, x, y, defaultDirection));
    }

}
```

***Scene File:***
*(using the registered Type)*

```js
import Phaser from 'phaser'
import { MyPlayer } from '@/players/MyPlayer'
import { CustomCursorKeys } from '@/types/phaser'
import { Direction } from '@/types/phaser'

export default class BaseScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  public cursors: CustomCursorKeys | null = null
  public myPlayer: MyPlayer | null = null

  constructor(key: string) {
    super(key)
  }

  create(param: { 
    map: Phaser.Tilemaps.Tilemap, 
    x: number, 
    y: number, 
    direction: Direction 
  }) {
    console.log('this.add.myPlayer', this.add.myPlayer)
    this.myPlayer = this.add.myPlayer(705, 500, 'up')
  }
}
```

***Game creation:***
*(Here you have to register the created plugin)*

```js
import { MPlayerPlugin } from '@/players/MyPlayer'
...
const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    ...
    plugins: {
        global: [
            { key: 'MPlayerPlugin', plugin: MPlayerPlugin, start: true}
        ]
    },
    ...
};
```